# Magento add custom options with programmatically importing products

Tags: php, magento

I'm programmatically importing simple products in Magento based on a .csv file. Everything works fine, but I have to add some values where I have created some custom attributes for. But I don't know how to add them.

I thought since I added the attribute set where the custom attributes are in, I could add them like
`$product->setCustomAttribute(value)`
but that doesn't work.

How can I add them?

Rest of the code for reference

```
if(($handle = fopen("werkbladvoorraad.csv", "r")) !== FALSE){
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE){
        $row++;

        if($row == 1){
            continue;
        }

    try{
        $product ->setStoreId(1)
                 ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
                 ->setAttributeSetId(4)
                 ->setTypeId('simple')
                 //->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
                 ->setSku($data[0])
                 ->setName($data[1])
                 //->setWeight()
                 ->setStatus(1)
                 ->setTaxClassId(2)
                 ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                 ->setManufacturer($data[14])
                 ->setColor($data[10])
                 ->setPrice($data[6])
                 ->setMaat_heren($data[4]) // CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE
                 ->setStockData(array(
                       'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                        'manage_stock'=>1, 
                        'min_sale_qty'=>1, 
                        'max_sale_qty'=>2, 
                        'is_in_stock' =>1, 
                        'qty' => 999 
                    ));
       $product->save();     
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo ($e->getMessage());
    }
  }  
}
```

**Note**

There are no error messages displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's silly, but you could try cleaning up your cache and then saving the custom attributes in question. If that doesn't work, try forcing the saving with:

```
$product->setMyCustomAttr('My Custom Attr');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'my_custom_attr');
```

Just make sure that you have already saved the product and loaded it again with its ID. In order to do that you would use

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
```

Let me know if this works properly :)